# A more pythonic way to find curve intersections

Tags: python, sorting, interpolation

I am currently interpolating measurements using cubic splines as shown in the picture:

[image: Interpolation of a normalised harmonic signal using cubic splines.]

The idea is I want to find the full width half-maximum of that interpolation. For that I'm using the small piece of code

```
f = interpolate.interp1d(hhg_data, signal_array, kind='cubic')
idx2 = np.argsort(np.abs(f(hhg_interp)-0.5))
```

which returns me the sorted indexes of the intersection with the line `y=0.5`. However, I want the solutions of on the left edge and the right edge of the curve and sometimes it gives me back two points that are consecutive. Is there a elegant pythonic way to avoid this? At least much better than my hacky solution:

```
idx_sorted = []
counter = 0
counter2 = 0
while(counter <= 1):
    if idx2[counter2] != idx2[counter2-1]+1 and idx2[counter2] !=   idx2[counter2-1]-1:
        idx_sorted.append(idx2[counter2])
        counter+=1
    counter2+=1
```

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `hhg_interp` is sorted and there is only one maximum and would like to do a gridsearch (i.e. calculate your function at discrete points and work with those values), I would do the following:

```
# hhg_interp could be something like
# hhg_interp = linspace(18.5, 19.5, 10000) 
y = f(hhg_interp) # hhg_interp is an array filled with finely 
                  # spaced x-axis values
# get the indices for all y larger than the half maximum (0.5 in this case)
indices_above_fwhm = np.where(y>0.5)[0] 
# if you're interested in the indices
# the first element of the "indices larger then the half maximum" array
# corresponds to your left edge
index_left_edge = indices_above_fwhm[0]
# the last element of the "indices larger then the half maximum array"
# corresponds to your right edge
index_right_edge = indices_above_fwhm[-1]


# then you can get the corresponding x-axis values for these indices:
x_left = hhg_interp[index_left_edge]
x_right = hhg_interp[index_right_edge]

# or directly get the x-axis values of the left and right edges
cond = y > 0.5 # select all points that are above your half maximum
x_left, x_right = hhg_interp[cond][[0,-1]] # then get the first 
                              # and last of the points above maximum
```

Is that the information you are looking for?

Comment: Not really sure, hhg_interp is basically an np.array of x-axis variable. In that case you could take it as hhg_interp=linspace(18.5, 19.5, 10000) just to have a fine grid to plot f against.

Comment: Added some code for calculating the indices of the left and right edges as well as some more comments. Does this help to clarify?

Comment: Ah ok I see. Thanks it's working nicely. Maybe I'll work around this idea to adapt it best to my cases of interest.